# How do I add 3 Images on my home page horizontal in Joomla?

Tags: javascript, joomla

I want to add three images on my home page in Joomla:

[image]

Comment: I've removed the "urgent" begging from the question, but they persist in the image. Please don't do this - your question is read by **volunteers**, who answer questions at their leisure.

Comment: I'd like a couple of million pounds in my bank account, but I'm going to have to work for it. Please show us what you've already tried. You may also want to have a read of the Joomla documentation for adding modules to your site

Answer (score 0):

Upload your images on the server where Joomla is running : left column of the administration panel -> Media -> Upload (green button on the left top).
Create a `Custom Module` : `Extensions -> Modules -> New`, then in the Select a Module Type list, choose Custom HTML.
Then if you don't use any particular editor (I mean you type HTML code) in the text part of the module, you can type something like `<img src="images/<<the-path-you-chosed-for-your-images>>" alt="<<your-message>>" width="<<the-width>>" height="<<the-height>>" />` to insert an image. My advice : don't specify the width and height and the images will automatically adapt to the size of the window.
Finally, assuming you're using the Protostar template, assign the module to the `Footer` position of Protostar.